# Progress bar in wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

Can anyone help me how can I integrate a progress bar in one of my methods? What I mean is when I execute a method example to extract zip files I will show a progress bar to know the progress of my method and as the method is done, the progress bar will reach 100%.

Here is my code for extracting files where in I want to add a progress bar

```
public void ExtractFiles()
{
     foreach (var file in d.GetFiles("*."))
     {
          if (!Directory.Exists(targetPath))
              Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);

          if (!File.Exists(targetPath + file.Name))
          {
              Directory.Move(file.FullName, targetPath + file.Name);
          }
          else
          {
              File.Delete(targetPath + file.Name);
              Directory.Move(file.FullName, targetPath + file.Name);
          }
     }
}
```

I want to know how can I show the % of my progress bar depending in the progress of my method.

Comment: What have you explored and tried about a progress bar so far?

Comment: What are you asking? How to create a progress bar? How to bind progress bar to value? How to calculate the value? How to use a dispatcher?

Comment: @bit, I've tried to use a simple progress bar that progress even if my process is done. I dont know how can I integrate it with my method

Comment: I see you could use a simple event based mechanism to update the progress bar.. Are the Progresssbar and ExtractFiles() in different classes?

Comment: @Bit, How can I do that?

Comment: @bit, My progress bar and extract file is at the same form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have it in the same form it should be pretty straight forward..

Assuming the you have named you ProgressBar as pb, you could try something like this..

```
public void ExtractFiles()
{
     var total = d.GetFiles("*.").count();
     var progressChange =  100/total;

    foreach (var file in d.GetFiles("*."))
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(targetPath))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);

        if (!File.Exists(targetPath + file.Name))
        {
            Directory.Move(file.FullName, targetPath + file.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            File.Delete(targetPath + file.Name);
            Directory.Move(file.FullName, targetPath + file.Name);
        }
        pb.Value += progressChange;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait I'll try this one.

Comment: thanks. It do work. I'll just add some modifications.

Comment: it didn't full the bar

Answer (score 0):

Copied the  code from @bit and changed little bit.

Try this:

```
public void ExtractFiles()
{
     var files = d.GetFiles("*.");
     int total = files.Count();
     var progressChange = 100/total;

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(targetPath))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);

        if (!File.Exists(targetPath + file.Name))
        {
            Directory.Move(file.FullName, targetPath + file.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            File.Delete(targetPath + file.Name);
            Directory.Move(file.FullName, targetPath + file.Name);
        }
        //Here is the little bit change I did.
        pb.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(()=>{
            pb.Value += progressChange;
        }));

    }
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: It didn't full the bar